Docker Desktop の更新後、データが全て消えた？
Docker Desktopを"Docker Desktop 4.31.1 (153621)"にアップデートしました。アップデート前のバージョンは覚えていません。
その後表示されたContainers、Images、Volumesのどれも空となっていました。
一応コマンドでも確認しましたが同じく空となっていました。
さらにWSLの状態を確認したところ以下のようになっていました。
> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2

何故かdocker-desktop-dataだけが停止していました。Windowsの再起動で起動すると思いましたが起動しませんでした。
停止したdocker-desktop-dataを起動しようとすると以下のようなメッセージが出力されます。
> wsl -d docker-desktop-data
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:754: getpwuid(0) failed 2
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2

<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return

類似した内容で、Docker Desktop自体が起動しなくなりその原因がWSLの規定値がdocker-desktopとなっていることが原因のエラーが存在するようです。その解消法としてUbuntuを入れ直した上で規定値をUbuntuに設定する、を試してみましたが上記エラーは解消されませんでした。
このエラーを解消しdocker-desktop-dataを起動する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/14139 によれば、4.31.xではWSLでIPV6が有効になっていないといけないとのこと。C:\User\ユーザ名.wslconfig に
kernelCommandLine = ipv6.disable=1のような記載があったりしないでしょうか。

ありがとうございます。もともと書いていませんでした。一応値を"0"にしたりと試しては見ましたが変わりませんでした。
問題の現象は以下のURLにあるようにver4.8.0以前からver4.31.0にバージョンアップすると発生する現象なようで、コンテナやボリュームなどが"非表示になる現象"が発生するようです。ダウングレードする旨あったのでそのように対応しましたがデータが削除されてしまいました。正確に私がした対応はDocker Desktopのアンインストールと、（4.8以前が公式ではダウンロード不可なため）4.24あたりの再インストールです。アンインストール時にWSL2のdocker-desktop-data等が削除されたためデータが正真正銘削除されました。
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#known-issues

ほほう。そんな問題もあるのですね...。docker-desktop-dataに関してはDocker Desktopをアンインストールしても残ってたような記憶がおぼろげにありますが、%LocalAppData%\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx自体が消えちゃってる状態でしょうか？

すみません。ext4.vhdx確認していませんでした。Ver4.24をすでにインストールしたのでもう確認できないですね。"wsl -l -v"コマンドで確認した時に"Ubuntu"以外が消えていました。ひょっとしてこれも非表示になっていただけでext4.vhdxはあったりしたかもしれませんね。
